# Exchanging data between 2 methods in 2 different classes

Tags: java

Im quite new to Java and this might be a basic doubt. But please help. 
I have a class as below:

```
public class EnterLeaveHandler implements IOtfHandler {
    public void handle(java.lang.Object ... args) {

        long time = (Long) args[0];
        int func = (Integer) args[1];
        int cpuid = (Integer) args[2];
        int source = (Integer) args[3];
}
```

I have another class:

```
public class DefFunctionHandler implements IOtfHandler {

    public void handle(Object... args) {

        int stream = (Integer) args[0];
        int func = (Integer) args[1];
        String name = (String) args[2];
        int funcgroup = (Integer) args[3];
        int source = (Integer) args[4];
    }
}
```

So like you can see..there are 2 different classes, which have the same method, but receive different data. I need to get an input from the user for the  "String name" in `DefFunctionHandler` class, and I identify the given name with the name in the file that I have...then correlate it with other data in the method like `funcgroup` and `func`. The same `func` is there in the other class too. So I need to make a comparison between them to get the data in the other class like time, etc.

So the data in the methods can be compared to the data structure in C...how do I implement such a structure in Java? I read that structs are similar to classes in Java. But in my case, I have the data in methods and not classes. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: This is not really Java-like code. Interface with a method with an Object array? 
Anyway I would turn the interface into an abstract class and move the common variables there and create an equals(IOtFHandler) method for it.

Comment: Are these methods of yours or existing methods?

Comment: @fge This is part of Eclipse plugin application that Im developing and these methods are defined by me using an interface.

Comment: "that I am developing" -- then don't start coding like that! It is "anti Java"

Comment: @BalintBako This is Java in Eclipse. I have an interface IOtfHandler which implements the method handle. So you mean to say, by converting interface into a class, it will be like nested classes?

Comment: Also, I'd say don't use varargs (`Objects ... args`) unless you truly don't know how many arguments will be passed in. In your case, you're expecting 4 args, then 5. So your program should reflect this by means of proper method signatures. The method signature should tell you what goes into a method, and what comes out... having varargs is ambiguous (bad programming habbit).

Comment: Maybe that does not answer your question, but using two overriding methods with the same name and different arguments is not a good design. You should consider changing the design if you can. For example, making two classes with two different method and put the variable as fields in each classes.

Comment: @SnakeDoc The handle method reads from an external source, and it is called like this: `IOtfHandler enterhandler = new EnterLeaveHandler();IOtfHandler newhandler = new DefFunctionHandler(); o.otfjni_set_handler(OtfJni.OTF_ENTER_RECORD, enterhandler, "liii"); o.otfjni_set_handler(OtfJni.OTF_DEFFUNCTION_RECORD, newhandler, "iisii");` So I guess having a single method shud be fine for now.

Comment: @user2358330 simple or not, once you start down the "throw best practices to the wind" train, then all bets are off. I would do this with some constructors to initialize any values I needed from within the object, then use setters and getters to access the data. so then in your external method call, you would just populate it's arguments with the return values from your getters.

Comment: @SnakeDoc thanks for the advice! I shall change the varargs part once im done dealing with comparing data in different methods :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To Answer Your Original Question

Long story short, you can't access method variables externally. What you *want* to do is make those variables **fields** within the class. Putting them outside the method means they stick around after the method is done, and it means you can access them from outside.

```
public class EnterLeaveHandler implements IOtfHandler {
    private long time;
    private int func;
    private int cpuid;
    private int source;

    // Please don't use varargs like this; read the whole answer!!
    public void handle(Object ... args) {
        time = (Long) args[0];
        func = (Integer) args[1];
        cpuid = (Integer) args[2];
        source = (Integer) args[3];
    }
}
```

Then you access them by creating **getters** and **setters**:

```
public long getTime() {
    return time;
}
public void setTime(long t) {
    time = t;
}
// etc...
```

---

### HOWEVER, Some Suggestions...

Your code is... strange, to say the least. It's also very non-Java-like. As much as possible, you should try to avoid having multiple overriding methods that need different data. Also, you normally want to initialize your *fields* in the **constructor**, not in some other method.

It's not clear how much of the code you have access to, but if you're able to rewrite the interface, I would **definitely** do so. `Object` varargs in an interface is just weird. The reason for using an interface is so that you can call an interface method with identical parameters and, regardless of the object type underneath, something useful will happen. It defeats the point of the interface to have two implementations of the same method require totally different arguments. The following code demonstrates why this is:

```
IOtfHandler h1 = new EnterLeaveHandler();
IOtfHandler h2 = new DefFunctionHandler();
h1.handle(0, 0, 0, 0);
h2.handle(0, 0, 0, 0); // Crashes with ClassCastException!! :(
                       // And would also crash two lines later with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

**Much better** to just make them different methods entirely.You know what variables you're expecting, so you should take advantage of that fact. Your method signatures would be far better off looking something like this:

```
public class EnterLeaveHandler implements IOtfHandler {
    public void handle(long time, int func, int cpuid, int source) {
    // Do things with your shiny new variables
}
public class DefFunctionHandler implements IOtfHandler {
    public void handle(int stream, int func, String name, int funcgroup, int source) {
        // Do things with your shiny new variables
    }
}
```

As others have suggested, if the "real" method signatures are not identical, you shouldn't be using an interface. Better to use an abstract base class instead, to hold what little data is common between them:

```
abstract class IOtfHandler {
    private int source;
    private int func;

    public void setSource(int source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    // etc
}
class EnterLeaverHandler extends IOtfHandler {
    private long time;
    // etc
}
class DefFunctionHandler extends IOtfHandler {
    private String name;
    // etc
}
```

Of course, if you set all the variables in the constructors, you may be able to add an abstract `handle()` method to the base class, since then that method should have the same signature, and take no arguments at all!

---

### Final Result

So if we pull together all the changes I've talked about-- moving the method variables into *fields*, using *getters* and *setters*, using *useful method signatures*, using *constructors*, and using a *base class* instead of a misleading interface, we end up with something like this:

```
abstract class IOtfHandler {
    private int source;
    private int func;

    public void setSource(int source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public int getSource() {
        return source;
    }
    public void setFunc(int func) {
        this.func = func;
    }
    public int getFunc() {
        return func;
    }

    // abstract handle method
    abstract public void handle();
}

class EnterLeaverHandler extends IOtfHandler {
    private long time;
    private int cpuid;

    // getters and setters
    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setCpuId(int cpuid) {
        this.cpuid = cpuid;
    }
    public int getCpuId() {
        return cpuid;
    }

    // constructor
    public EnterLeaverHandler(long time, int cpuid, int source, int func) {
        setTime(time);
        setCpuId(cpuid);
        setSource(source);
        setFunc(func);
    }

    // handle method
    public void handle() {
        System.out.println("EnterLeaverHandler.handle()");
        // Do whatever class-specific handling you might want to do in here.
    }
}

class DefFunctionHandler extends IOtfHandler {
    private String name;
    private int funcGroup;
    private int stream;

    // getters and setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setFuncGroup(int funcGroup) {
        this.funcGroup = funcGroup;
    }
    public int getFuncGroup() {
        return funcGroup;
    }
    public void setStream(int stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }
    public int getStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    // constructor
    public DefFunctionHandler(String name, int funcGroup, int stream, int source, int func) {
        setName(name);
        setFuncGroup(funcGroup);
        setStream(stream);
        setSource(source);
        setFunc(func);
    }

    // handle method
    public void handle() {
        System.out.println("DefFunctionHandler.handle()");
        // Do whatever class-specific handling you might want to do in here.
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IOtfHandler h1 = new DefFunctionHandler("name", 0, 0, 0, 0);
        IOtfHandler h2 = new EnterLeaverHandler(0, 0, 0, 0);
        h1.handle();
        h2.handle();
    }
}
```

Comment: good answer, but please get rid of varargs, it's a bad habbit and is not used appropriately here (we know how many variables we are expecting).

Comment: @Henry The handle method reads from an external source, and it is called like this: `IOtfHandler enterhandler = new EnterLeaveHandler();IOtfHandler newhandler = new DefFunctionHandler(); o.otfjni_set_handler(OtfJni.OTF_ENTER_RECORD, enterhandler, "liii"); o.otfjni_set_handler(OtfJni.OTF_DEFFUNCTION_RECORD, newhandler, "iisii");` So I guess having a single method shud be fine.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I'm trying to address one problem at a time. Trust me, I realize how nasty the varags are. I address that in the second section to avoid confusion.

Comment: @HenryKeiter I just read that part. Thanks for mentioning it. However, I've added an edit to your post, having a permanent record for googler's who happen by that shows use of varargs in this fashion makes me shudder! Better to have the record show a (more)proper use.

Comment: ok, your answer is likely going to be the accepted answer - so for completeness, it would be better is `handle()` didn't use direct references to the private vars, but instead followed the class's contract as any other method/object should, and use the public setters and getters.

Comment: @user2358330 "It compiles" is really, really not the same as "it is good". Just because it works now does not mean (or even suggest) that it will work when you want to change something. Instead of settling for "good enough", do it right the first time and save yourself hours of frustration when you need to enhance it six months from now.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I'm working on a "final version" edit to put all the various suggestions together. Just give me a couple minutes :)

Comment: @HenryKeiter thank you for the very complete answer now, +1 to all your updates.

Comment: @HenryKeiter thanks for patiently answering my question. I will definitely make the changes that you have suggested.

Comment: @user2358330 this is a well formed answer now. Good advice... (i'd pick it as "correct" if it were me ;-P )

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the variables class variables, all you have to do is move their declaration outside of the method.  In other words, your code for the EnterLeaveHandler might look like this:

```
public class EnterLeaveHandler implements IOtfHandler {

    long time;
    int func;
    int cpuid;
    int source;

    public void handle(java.lang.Object ... args) {

        time = (Long) args[0];
        func = (Integer) args[1];
        cpuid = (Integer) args[2];
        source = (Integer) args[3];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue I have with the above is the the class is a "handler" class not a DTO (data transfer object) that would carry data between methods / classes. Ideally, there would be a separate DTO encapsulating the data that needs to be shared. As an additional point for the OP, one class instance will need a reference to the other in order to pass the data.

Comment: varargs is a bad programming habbit here, please update your post to show a proper method signature.

Comment: I agree, SnakeDoc, but the interface he is implementing seems to require the Object... form.

Comment: @DavidChristo right, but a permanent record on SO showing use like this is bad. Also, this brings to question... the Interface should be rebuilt to be better as well. Since an Interface acts like a contract enforcer, it should expect an exact number of arguments of specific types to get it's work done... much like a Bouncer at a night club has a list of who's allowed in and with how many.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your objects to have proper constuctors and setters/getters

This gives the benefit of protecting all your private variables and forcing other classes to adhere to your classe's "contract" by only allowing them to access it's inner variables via those setters/getters and constructor. Now you just instantiate the object, then use ti's methods to manipulate it.

Here is an example from your first example class:

```
public class EnterLeaveHandler implements IOtfHandler {

    private long time;
    private int func, cpuid, source;

    public EnterLeavehandler(long time, int func, int cpuid, int source) {

        this.time = time;
        this.func = func;
        this.cpuid = cpuid;
        this.source = souce;

    }

    public long getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getFunc() {
        return this.func;
    }

    public void setFunc(int func) {
        this.func = func;
    }

    public int getCPUID() {
        return this.cpuid;
    }

    public void setCPUID(int cpuid) {
        this.cpuid = cpuid;
    }

    public int getSource() {
        return this.source;
    }

    public void setSource(int source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void handle(long t, int f, int c, int s) {

        this.setTime(t);
        this.setFunc(f);
        this.setCPUID(c);
        this.setSource(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract super class for your classes. Extend this with your classes and init the parameters in the handle call.

```
public abstract class AbstarctFunctionHandler implements IOtfHandler { 
   long time; 
   int func; 
   int cpuid; 
   int source 
   //add getters and setters, if you fancy

   public boolean equals(AbstarctFunctionHandler obj){ 
      //compare variables 
      return true;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The best solution I could think of 
1. is create a getter and setter

```
 public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

2.create a wrapper method to do the comparsion prior to calling the individual method.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This of course would assume that the variable name was declared as an instance variable for the class, rather than be a method-local variable.

Comment: These are method variables not fields so therefore this doesn't apply. Once the variable are converted to field then this is appropriate.